# Restkit 2.0 'managedObjectContext' not found on object of type

Tags: ios, core-data, restkit, restkit-0.20

Excuse the possible noob question. I'm building an app with Restkit 2.0 and having issues implementing the Core Data features. Following [this tutorial](https://github.com/RestKit/RKGist/blob/master/TUTORIAL.md) I added the following code to my AppViewController (all other view controllers extend this class).

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.shadowImage = [UIImage new];

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSURL *modelURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Jumplytics" ofType:@"momd"]];
    // NOTE: Due to an iOS 5 bug, the managed object model returned is immutable.
    NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel = [[[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL] mutableCopy];
    RKManagedObjectStore *managedObjectStore = [[RKManagedObjectStore alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:managedObjectModel];

    // Initialize the Core Data stack
    [managedObjectStore createPersistentStoreCoordinator];

    NSPersistentStore __unused *persistentStore = [managedObjectStore addInMemoryPersistentStore:&error];
    NSAssert(persistentStore, @"Failed to add persistent store: %@", error);

    [managedObjectStore createManagedObjectContexts];

    // Set the default store shared instance
    [RKManagedObjectStore setDefaultStore:managedObjectStore];

    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.managedObjectContext = managedObjectStore.mainQueueManagedObjectContext;
}
```

I am getting the error:

```
property managedObjectContext not found on object of type 'AppViewController'
```

What can I do to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably don't want this code in `viewDidLoad` in your superclass because that means it's being run for each subclass. So, each VC will have its own Core Data stack. It's more likely that you want a single Core Data stack that is used by all controllers (possibly in a singleton data controller).

Your error:

> property managedObjectContext not found on object of type 'AppViewController'

seems unrelated to RestKit. It means that you are using `self.managedObjectContext` when you don't have a property named `managedObjectContext`. You just need to add the property so that it can be referenced.

Comment: You might want to add more code from the .h / continuation category of your `AppViewController`...

Comment: Oh duh. The error is definitely occurring because I didn't define the property in the header file. That makes sense to not have it in viewDidLoad--would this be better to initialize in the AppDelegate then?